# iPhone - saving digits in code = smaller binary?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I see several programmers, including Apple, creating codes where they declare stuff like this:

```
CGRect myRect = CGRectMake (0.f, 0.f, 20.f, 10.f);
```

or

```
[myView setAlpha:.7f];
```

instead of

```
CGRect myRect = CGRectMake (0.0f, 0.0f, 20.0f, 10.0f);
// and
[myView setAlpha:0.7f];
```

what the advantage of doing that? Smaller final binary? Faster code?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just laziness/taste: both `0.f` and `0.0f` as well as `.7f` and `0.7f` produce exactly the same floating point numbers. There is no difference whatsoever, it's only that the C syntax allows to omit the zero before or after that dot.

Comment: In other words, it's just less typing.

Comment: ok, thanks. I was suspecting that, but asked just in case... :D